# FMDB error : No Such table

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb, sqlitemanager

I created new DB in Documents using `SQLite` Manager.
Created a table there too with a sample row.
This code I am using for db path :

```
  +(ModelManager *) getInstance
{

    if(!instance)
    {
        instance=[[ModelManager alloc]init];
        instance.database=[FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Inventorydb.sqlite"]];
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Now when I am using function to display data; it shows :
DB Error: 1 "no such table: inventorydata"
Code for Display data is like this :

```
-(void) displayData
{
    [instance.database open];
    FMResultSet *resultSet=[instance.database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM inventorydata"];
    if(resultSet)
    {
        while([resultSet next])
        NSLog(@"UPC : %@    Name : %@",[resultSet stringForColumn:@"upc"],[resultSet stringForColumn:@"name"]);
    }
    [instance.database close];
}
```

Image Showing Created table in sqlite manager.

Whats the issue here.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a MCVE (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query), to prove that all tables you mention do exist. E.g. inventorydata.

Comment: did you create the Table? with that code you only have created the DataBase

Comment: I created Table and db from sqlite manager GUI. @ReinierMelian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to copy DB file inside App Delegate file.

```
    [Util copyFile:@"Inventorydb.sqlite"];
```